# mpl_connect inside a loop in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

It's not *literally* inside a loop, but I use `fig.canvas.mpl_connect` inside a method of my class `PPlot()`.

In the main program I just create the plot first (with `simple_plot()`) and then call the `update()` method to re-draw the points:

```
plot = PPlot()
plot.simple_plot(x_values, y_values)
...
plot.update(x_values, y_values)
...
plot.update(x_values, y_values)
```

This is what my code looks like so far (`__onpick` just print the coordinates of the point picked):

```
def update(self, x_values, y_values) -> None:
    self.sc.set_data(x_values, y_values)
    event_handler = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.__onpick)

    self.axis.relim()
    self.axis.autoscale_view(True, True, True)

    self.fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(1*10e-10)

    self.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(event_handler)
```

The output is:

```
Point = (1,2)
```

On the other hand, if I don't put the last `self.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(event_handler)`, when I use `update()` multiple times the output will be:

```
Point = (1,2)
Point = (1,2)
Point = (1,2)
...
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Am I doing something wrong? This approach doesn't seems good to me.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, `__onpick` doesn't just print the points, It also do some other things. In fact, the real code is:

```
def update(self, x_values, y_values, biglist) -> None:
    ...
    event_handler = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', 
                          lambda event: self.__onpick(event, biglist))
    ...
```

If I initialize `fig.canvas.mpl_connect` in the constructor or elsewhere outside  `update()`, I can't use the list of the 3rd parameter.

Comment: It's not clear why you would want to disconnect the event; of course if it's diconnected, it will not be working. Can you explain what the purpose of this is?

Comment: If I disconnect it, everything work just fine; If I don't, I think that in every call to `update()` one pick_event is added and that's why I get multiple prints of `Point = (x, y)`

Comment: So biglist is different for every plot?

Comment: yes, it's used to get information of the point picked based on the coordinates

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine to make `biglist` a class variable and simply use it inside the `onpick` method, instead of supplying it to the `onpick` method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class PPlot():
    def __init__():
        self.biglist = None
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.cid = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)

    def update(self, x_values, y_values, biglist):
        self.biglist = biglist
        self.sc.set_data(x_values, y_values)

        self.axis.relim()
        self.axis.autoscale_view(True, True, True)

        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.pause(1*10e-10)


    def onpick(event=None):
        print (self.biglist)
        # do something with biglist



plot = PPlot()
plot.simple_plot(x_values, y_values)
#...
plot.update(x_values1, y_values1, biglist1)
#...
plot.update(x_values2, y_values2, biglist2)
```